# A homeomorphism of a topological space with itself maps a set into one of the same category

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Prove: If $h$ is a homeomorphism of $S$ onto $S$ and if $E\subset S$, then $E$ and $h(E)$ have the same category in $S$.

Rudin, *Functional Analysis, 2/e*, p.43.

(My own answer follows below.)

Comment: You might want to add to your question that you were asking the question and providing an answer at the same time (that one people don't downvote or try to close because of "lack of context").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need to show if $E$ is of the first category in $S$, then $h(E)$ is also of the first category in $S$. Let $(E_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be nowhere dense sets s.t. $E=\cup_i E_i$. Then $h(E)=\cup_i h(E_i).$ We only need to show the $h(E_i)$'s are nowhere dense. By way of contradiction, suppose some $h(E_i)$ is *not* nowhere dense, i.e. $\overline{h(E_i)}$ has nonempty interior, which let's call $O$. Then $h^{-1}(O)$ is nonempty, open, and is a subset of $h^{-1}(\overline{h(E_i)}) \subset \overline{h^{-1}(h(E_i))}=\overline{E_i}$. (By Theorem 18.1 in Munkres 2/e, $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff for every subset $A$ of $X$, one has $f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}.$) Hence $E_i$ is *not* nowhere dense---a contradiction.